# Finding a formula for a repeating sequence of 1's and -1's

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a simple formula for the sequence $(a_n)$ given by $(1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,\cdots)$

(with the repeating pattern 1,1,-1), starting with $n=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$${ \left( -1 \right)  }^{ (n+1)\mod 3  }$$ where $n$ starts from $1$.

Or

$${ \left( -1 \right)  }^{ (n+2 ){ \mod 3 }  }$$ where $n$ starts from $0$.

Comment: why doesn't n start from 0?

Comment: @imranfat yes, also. It can be modified. I wrote what occured to me first.

Answer (score 4):

$$a_n=\frac{1-2\,\mathrm j^n-2\,\mathrm j^{2n}}3\quad\text{where}\quad \mathrm j=\frac{-1+\mathrm i\,\sqrt3}2=\mathrm e^{2\mathrm i\pi/3}$$

---

More generally, every sequence $(\alpha_n)_{n\geqslant3}$ of period $3$ can be written as
$$
\alpha_n=A+B\,\mathrm j^n+C\,\mathrm j^{2n},
$$
for some well chosen $(A,B,C)$, because $\{1,\mathrm j,\mathrm j^2\}$ are the three solutions of the equation $z^3=1$.

Comment: hmm, can we write this in a cleaner from, like the Binet-formula for the Fibonacci-numbers? I tried a bit but did not get the correct idea...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms This **is** the exact equivalent of Binet formula for the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Well, I've also tried to rewrite this in some more symmetric exposition and remove the somehow "inhomogenic" summand $1$ , but it gives only microscospic improvement this or that way. So I think, I simply should go with this, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

If $p(x) = \frac{1}{2}x (x-1)$, then $a_n = 1-2p(n \mod 3)$.

Here is nicer one (assuming that $n$ starts from $1$):

Let $a_n = 1-2\left( \frac{\cos(2 \pi \frac{n}{3})+1}{3} \right)$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1-4\cos\left(2\pi\cdot\frac{n+1}3\right)}3$$

Answer (score 1):

Starting with $n=0$ : $$2\cdot|(n+2)\bmod 3-1|-1$$
Starting with $n=1$ : $$2\cdot(n^2 \bmod 3)-1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$2\left(3\left\lfloor{n+1\over3}\right\rfloor-n\right)^2-1$$

**Added later**:  Inspired by CODE's nice answer, here's another, simpler formula along the same lines:

$$-1-2\left(\left\lfloor {n\over3}\right\rfloor+ \left\lfloor {-n\over3}\right\rfloor\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$(-1)^{[\frac{n}{3}]+[\frac{-n}{3}]+1}$

Answer (score 0):

$a_{n+1} = (-1)\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}} \, a_1=1,a_2=1$

or

$a_{n+1} = (-1)a_na_{n-1} \,\,, a_1=1,a_2=1$

This theme can be used to generate other sequences like $1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,...$:

$b_{n+2} = (-1)b_{n-1}b_{n}b_{n+1} \,\,, b_1=1,b_2=1,b_3=1$

Answer (score 0):

A recursive expression:
$$ a_1 = 1\\ a_2=1 \\ a_{k+2}=-a_{k+1} \cdot a_k $$